# How do I add a `\label` to a figure in an Org-Mode file that I'm going to export via LaTeX?

Tags: linux, emacs, latex, org-mode

How do I add a `\label` to a figure in an Org-Mode file that I'm going to export via LaTeX?

`example.org`:

```
#+CAPTION: This is the caption
#+NAME: fig:org_label
[[./figure.png]]

This is a link to the figure [[fig:org_label]], but I'd like to 
use \ref{fig:org_label} to get the figure's number.
```

What/where do I add a command, in Org-Mode so that an appropriate `\label` command
gets inserted into the graphics context of the TeX output?

Comment: Can we assume you are talking about emacs? On which OS?

Comment: OS is Linux, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't matter, but you never know. There may be differences between emacs implementations and org-mode versions etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example:

```
* Test

  #+CAPTION: insert figure caption here
  #+NAME: fig-1
  [[./figure.png]]

  By looking at figure [[fig-1]] we can see how referencing a figure works.
```

exports to this on my system:

```
\section{Test}
\label{sec-1}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{./figure.png}
\caption{\label{fig-1}insert figure caption here}
\end{figure}

By looking at figure \ref{fig-1} we can see how referencing a figure work.
```

using Emacs 23.4.1 and Org mode 8.0.5. This is the resulting pdf:
[image].

I guess I am missing a point in what you are saying, but it seems to me that at least in this version of org, the exporter does exactly what you want. If not, in which way should the behavior differ?

In case this is the behavior you want and you only have an older version of org-mode installed together with emacs on your system, then you can look at the org-mode manual in this section http://orgmode.org/org.html#Installation to get some hints on how to install a more recent version.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your example does not work in all settings is that by default, org-mode replaces the `#+NAME: fig:org_label` you provide with an automatically generated label (to guarantee uniqueness); org-mode links like `[[fig:org_label]]` will export properly, but `\ref{fig:org_label}` will not work. If you wish to use `\ref{}` commands (useful in particular to get page references, like `\pageref{fig:org_label}`), you need to set the `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` preference. Put this in your initialization file:

`(setq org-latex-prefer-user-labels t)`